# Data type mismatch in criteria expression when try adding data to excel DB

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

i trying to add data to excel using oleDb

this is my code:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/shaynaga/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/requestSystem/requestSystem/dataset.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
conn.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Request id],[Request name],[Dua date],[priority]) values(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)";
myComm = new OleDbCommand(sql , conn);
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", 1);
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", "bla bla");
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", "10/10/2014");
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", "Low");
myComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

i'm not sure why i get error

any Suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to reference a cell range as well as a sheet for the insert.

Comment: what you mean when you say cell range?
when i need to put the reference?

Comment: You say insert into Sheet1, but that's not a complete Excel range reference.  You also might want to check the spelling of your field names.